# C# on MACOS, how can I unminimize a minimized window?

Tags: c#, macos

In this user32.dll function we can unminimize windows... Does MACOS have an alternative function that does similar things? I have been unable to find anything thus far but I am NOT a mac user and I am very unfamiliar with developing on macos.

There was one vague other stack overflow question that just said, "maybe" and said to look in pinvoke.net but I couldn't even find mac functions listed there.

```
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int nCmdShow);
```

Comment: In macOS you have [`deminiturize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419334-deminiaturize).

Comment: Is there anything to move the window?

Comment: [`setFrame`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419753-setframe)

Comment: Do I need to use any special dll type mac thing to use these? I'm just programming in C# (unity) will I be able to call these by default?

Comment: @Rob I do not know how to use these... I'm in C# on Unity, how do I include these function calls? Do I need something similar to a DLL like for user32?

Comment: Needless to say, this is virtual [duplicate of your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57047295/1271826), closed for being too broad, and provided no new details here. But you’ve asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57065706/1271826) in which you’ve added the Unity tag, so we should just close/delete this one. Hopefully someone more familiar with Unity on macOS will be able to answer that other question.