# macOS on Unity, need to access deminiaturize functions

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine

I am trying to mimic user32.dll functions, and I know Mac has a couple similar ones, but I do not know how I am supposed to be using them within Unity (C#)

For example there is:

```
[Foundation.Export("deminiaturize:")]
public virtual void Deminiaturize (Foundation.NSObject sender);
```

But my C# code has no idea what Foundation is, etc.

I think this comes from Xamarin.mac.dll

Can I include Xamarin.mac.dll into my MAC project and then use these methods?

I am trying to minimize / unminize my game (mac) window.

The namespace is AppKit I think.

Comment: You can also try on the [Unity forums](https://forum.unity.com/), if you haven’t already. Good luck!

Comment: write a native plugin for macOS using Objective-C and call this method
[NSApplication.sharedApplication.mainWindow deminiaturize:sender]; see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419334-deminiaturize?language=objc